# Uncaught TypeError: Type error when calling push()

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to simulate smoke on `canvas`. I want to create a new smoke puff and push it in the puffs array but I keep getting the `"Uncaught TypeError: Type error"` error.
Anyone know what I'm missing?

```
var puffs = [];

this.tick = function() {
    var puffLength = puffs.length;
    if ( addPuffs && ( puffLength < maxParticles )) {
        puffs.push({ //THIS ONE IT WHAT GIVES ME THE ERROR
            posX: oPoint.x,
            posY: oPoint.y,
            scale: .1,
            age: 0
        });
    }

    for(var i = 0; i < puffLength; i++) {

        var currentPuff = puffs[i];

        if(currentPuff.age == maxLife) {
            puffs.splice(i, 1);
        } else {
            currentPuff.posX += windX,
            currentPuff.posY += windY,
            currentPuff.scale += growingSpeed,
            currentPuff.age++;
        }

    }

    this.render();

}
```

Comment: What is `oPoint.x` and `oPoint.y`?

Comment: There's a couple of variables that are defined earlier (oPoint.x and oPoint.x are x/y coordinates)

Comment: You want me to set up a fiddle?

Comment: That would be helpful, I suspect its one of those variables.

Comment: Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/jonigiuro/bcHPB/

Comment: But I don't think those variables are the problem, I tried logging them

Comment: err is her `if( addPuffs && ( puffLength < maxParticles )) addPuff is not defined`

Comment: I'm not sure it's related but notice that your for loop is erroneous since if an element is spliced the array at i > puffLength-1 will be out of bounds

Comment: I don't see `oPoint` defined anywhere, am I missing something? °°

Comment: @captain Sorry addPuffs is also a variable that is defined somewhere else (I'm using raphaeljs to move the particle emitter along a path when the user scrolls)

Comment: first thing i'd do is change the loop to 
 for(var i = puffLength-1; i >= 0; i--)
and see if that changes anything

Comment: sorry guys I'm still missing some variables on the fiddle, the thing is I'm using a lot of extra code where I define those, it would be a mess to copy everything up there..
Consider addPuffs and oPoint defined, I logged them and it works

Comment: I got it. I thought the problem was in there because I start pushing when I start scrolling and there it started logging the errors. But the moment is the same as it starts drawing on the canvas and the error was in the drawImage() call. I was passing it a string as source instead of an actuale new Image()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the provided fiddle, `addPuffs` is not defined.  You need to define this variable according to your business logic.  Also `oPoint.x` and `oPoint.y` are not defined, these must also be initialized according to your business logic.

```
var oPoint = {x:1, y:2}; //declare according to logic
var addPuffs = true; //some logic here
if ( addPuffs && ( puffLength < maxParticles )) {
    puffs.push({ //THIS ONE IT WHAT GIVES ME THE ERROR
        posX: oPoint.x,
        posY: oPoint.y,
        scale: .1,
        age: 0
    });
}
```

Also when using `drawImage()` on `canvas` I believe the first argument must be a `DOM` element and not a path to the image.

Try:

```
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = "/static/img/particle.png";
  //Omitted code
  ctx.drawImage(img,80,80,1,1);
```

Comment: addPuffs is defined (it's true when the user scrolls and goes false when it stops). sorry for not telling this earlier

Comment: If that is defined then you need to focus on `oPoint`

Comment: I tried this: console.log(oPoint.x, oPoint.y, addPuffs) and it logs 0.7774077543755 56.283392898185674 false. so the error has to be somewhere else

Comment: I get this error even when I use:
puffs.push({
                posX: 5,
                posY: 5,
                scale: .1,
                age: 0
            });

Comment: I got it. I thought the problem was in there because I start pushing when I start scrolling and there it started logging the errors. But the moment is the same as it starts drawing on the canvas and the error was in the drawImage() call. I was passing it a string as source instead of an actuale new Image()

Comment: @JonasGrumann I think the error is at `drawImage()` see my update

Comment: @JonasGrumann Exactly I just posted that in my answer a second ago.  Good work!